# paypal button change in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have implemented paypal SDK in codeigniter in my website. But while click pay button it showing "Continue to Review order". I need to change as "Pay now" or "continue" button. Is there any possibility to change this. please give me suggestion. thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Continue to review order" *already* is a continue button.

If you have no review order step and are going to capture immediately, you should change it to read "Pay Now". The parameter to do so will depend on which PayPal API you are using. For instance with the most current v2/checkout/orders API there is a parameter `payment_source.paypal.user_action = 'PAY_NOW'`.

Comment: @ Preston PHX thank you. Am using PayPal SDK lib.

Comment: That's nonspecific